# SegWit. Redeem script

Tags: bitcoin-core, segregated-witness

I'm experimenting with Segwit transactions.

Is it possible to restore redeem script, if I know
1. Address (Segwit)
2. Public key
3. Private key

Thank you.

Comment: There are many (infinite) different redeem scripts based on private key. Restoring is possible if you know what kind of script was generated

Answer (score 2):

The redeem script for a P2SH-P2WPKH address is relatively simple. You take the RIPEMD160 hash of the SHA256 hash of the public key (same as P2PKH), this is known as the keyhash. The public key *must* be in compressed form. Then the P2SH redeem script is just OP_0 followed by a push of the keyhash. The keyhash is 20 bytes so the redeem script will always be 22 bytes long: `0014{keyhash}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the redeem script from the public key. See line 86 here: https://github.com/Samourai-Wallet/samourai-wallet-android/blob/develop/app/src/main/java/com/samourai/wallet/segwit/P2SH_P2WPKH.java